# How to maintain serial integrity while changing column order in PostgreSQL tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I know there's no great way to officially alter column position in PostgreSQL, so my plan is to follow these steps:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo RENAME TO FooOld;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (Col1 dtype1 col2 dtype2 ....);
INSERT INTO Foo (Col1, Col2, Col3) (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM FooOld);
```

The issue I'm running into is validating the result. In particular, this table has a serial and the integrity of the data depends on the serial. I've been thinking about this and it might make sense to do a count on both tables and compare them, then do an inner join on all columns between the table and do a count on that join? If countold = countnew = countjoined, that would be a form of validation.

I can also do this as a task integrated with backend code, so it may be better to do the validation outside of SQL (only once it's confirmed the data in both tables is identical, would the old table be dropped) but I'm a little worried about screwing up the serial.

For some background: this is a production table of personal information and we're adding a few fields, and then there are some transformed columns for text vectorization, and we've decided to add a few more fields of personal information:

Before:

```
Serial, FirstName, LastName, DoB, vector1, vector2
```

Currently:

```
Serial, FirstName, LastName, DoB, vector1, vector2, Gender, SSN
```

Expected:

```
Serial, FirstName, LastName, Gender, SSN, vector1, vector2
```

But with more fields. For undisclosed reasons, we need to change the underlying schema and can't just change the order in our select statements.

Comment: Take a look at [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html). You can change the column order in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Why? There is no "way to officially alter column position", because column position id **totally irrelevant**. Column position in a row is to the row as row order is to the table. If you want a different order just specify the order you want in the query.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem I put in the title, looks like it's a straight SELECT with the serial included, which is fine. I am 100% aware that column position is irrelevant, thanks for wasting your breath.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I'm running into is validating the result. In particular, this table has a serial and the integrity of the data depends on the serial.

Then you must copy the serial column just like all others. Afterwards, use `setval` on the backing sequence to set it higher than the maximal value in the table.

But, as Belayer commented, the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: I am aware it is pointless, but unfortunately the people above me don't agree, so here I am.

Comment: I understand and commiserate. Defining a view won't do?